# Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, flutter-create, flutter-androidmanifest

After several times run and building my Flutter project suddenly I got the below error:

> I already have existed the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check `/Users/[user]/AndroidStudioProjects/[project name]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` for errors.
No application found for `TargetPlatform.android_arm64`.
Is your project missing an `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?`
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.